# How to use @Autowired MongoTemplate in multiple classes in spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, autowired, mongotemplate

Hi I'm relatively new to spring boot and I'm trying to use the mongotemplate
using autowired here's my class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Test implements CommandLineRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(ProducerConsumerApplication.class, args).close();
   }

  @Autowired
  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;



  @Override
  public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    new Myclass().insert();
  }
```

This is how my application.yml looks like.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 192.168.155.100:9092
    consumer:
      group-id: foo
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: 192.168.155.100
      port: 27017
      database: test
```

I am trying to use the mongo template in Myclass and I am calling it from the Test class but the mongotemplate is null. How should I be doing this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you also use the @Configuration annotation?

Comment: should I be using that on my main class or the class that I'm calling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make MyClass a Bean (annotate the class with `@Component` or return it from a `@Bean` method)
2. Autowire the `MyClass` bean in that `Test` class
3. In the `run` method call `insert()` on that field.